Unity Netcode Как сделать NetworkObject объект дочерним для не NetworkObject
Я делаю онлайн шутер и столкнулся с проблемой подбора оружия. Оружие изначально находится на земле и его надо подобрать. Оно содержит компонент NetworkObject. Также у меня есть игрок с архитектурой:

Player имеет компонент NetworkObject. Мне нужно оружие делать дочерним объектом к Hand, но Unity мне выдаёт ошибку: "InvalidParentException: Invalid parenting, NetworkObject moved under a non-NetworkObject parent".
А если я Камере добавляю компонент NetworkObject: "Spawning NetworkObjects with nested NetworkObjects is only supported for scene objects. Child NetworkObjects will not be spawned over the network!"
Как сделать Оружие дочерним объектом для Hand? (И игрок и оружие должны иметь NetworkObject)
